# Add virtual field for vehicle speed to OSM roads (tag='Highway')

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, openstreetmap, isochrone

I want to add additional speed values to my OSM data. There is a maxspeed value for some of the roads, but a lot of values are 'null'. Therefore, I would like to add additional values based on the OSM road type categorisation (e.g primary roads have a maximum speed of 90 in case the maxspeed value is 'null'). That way, I can make isochrone analysis based on more accurate maxspeed inputs.

So I tried the following in a virtual field of the OSM data using the expression builder:

```
If("maxspeed"is null) AND ("highway" =   'primary' ),90, if("maxspeed"is null) AND ("highway" =  'secondary'),50,  "maxspeed")
```

This should then be done for every category, but the formula is not working. Could anyone  help me out?

Comment: Your brackets don't make sense, otherwise the expression is solid. Still, it would be easier to use `CASE WHEN` instead of `if` - less nesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Erik suggests, a `CASE WHEN` statement works fine.

```
CASE 
      WHEN "maxspeed" IS null AND "highway" = 'primary' THEN 90 
      WHEN "maxspeed" IS null AND "highway" = 'secondary' THEN 50 
      ELSE "maxspeed" 
END
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like your brackets are no good.

You can try:

```
IF("maxspeed" is null AND "highway" = 'primary',   90,
IF("maxspeed" is null AND "highway" = 'secondary', 50, "maxspeed") )
```

But the CASE WHEN answer is more clear.